# Method Illuminate\View\View::__toString() must not throw an exception in Edit View

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm getting this error for the edit view for one of my resources.

Here's the view code in question:

```
<?php $__env->startSection('title'); ?>
Editing
<?php $__env->stopSection(); ?>

<?php $__env->startSection('header'); ?>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h1 class="page-header">
            //Editing Destination: <small><?php echo $destination->name; ?></small>
        </h1>
```

The error message makes it sound like it's trying to coerce $destination->name to a string and is unable to. However when I go check the value of $destination->name; with artisan tinker, it comes back as type string. And when I check out the database with phpmyadmin sure enough the value of name is there in the database (as "foo").

Is there somewhere else I should be looking for this? Am I misunderstanding why that error is being thrown?

Comment: I don't think `$destination->name` is the problem here. Can you show us the controller code that renders the view?